# When installing Ubuntu there is a handy app that enables testing which keyboard you actually have

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

When installing Ubuntu there is a handy app that helps you testing which keyboard layout you actually have attached to the computer.

Is there some way to relaunch this app_ The gnome settings require you know the keyb layout based on country and some random args in parenthesis.

Comment: Not sure if gnome settings the same/close enough to unity settings, but there is a keyboard icon to right of +/- buttons that will let you see what the keys will be of your pick.  This is the text input setting.  Found this link to similar question back for 14.04.   https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2227761

Comment: OK cheers, I guess its not possible without hacking at the ubituity app.